# The handler and views-handler tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Was just looking at the suggested edit queue, and saw there are a bunch of edits where someone removed [handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handler) from the question.

Instead, I changed most of these to [views-handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-handler), as [handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handler) is likely too generic.  I fat-fingered one and accidentally made [views-hander](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-hander) which should probably be deleted.  I am not finding any questions using [handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handler), so it can probably be deleted too.

I started to create a tag wiki for this, but I am not sure where to begin with this.  Any thoughts on a good description of what views handlers do?

Comment: Tags that are not used from any question are automatically deleted within 24 hours.

Comment: Coolio.  Wasn't totally clear about this.

Answer (score 1):

The generic definition I can find for a Views handler is [the following](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-handlers), given in the Views documentation installed with the module.

> In Views, a handler is an object that is part of the view and is part of the query building flow.
>
> Handlers are objects; much of the time, the base handlers will work, but often you'll need to override the handler for something. One typical handler override will be `views_handler_filter_operator_in()` which allows you to have a filter select from a list of options; you'll need to override this to provide your list.

Clearly, the definition is too generic, as it must include different type of Views handlers, i.e. field handlers, sort handlers, filter handlers, argument handlers, and relationship handlers.

The text I reported here could not suit a tag wiki, depending on the license for that text. I think we can use that text to create a tag wiki; eventually, the tag wiki can contains link to resource pages, such as the [Views 2 API Manual](http://views.doc.logrus.com/).

Comment: That was essentially my struggle.  I know what they do, and they are a key concept for working with views programmatically, but a succinct statement to start out a tag wiki is rather difficult to craft for these.

Comment: The succinct statement is necessary only in the excerpt, to give a rough idea of when the tag should be used. In this case, the excerpt is almost not necessary, in the same way it would not be necessary to add an excerpt for a tag like [tag:php] on Stack Overflow: The users who use that tag should already know what PHP is; if they don't know what PHP is, they would not probably ask a question about PHP. I don't think it is possible to make a succinct statement that makes everybody understand what a view handler is; it is probably enough a sentence that makes the users check the full tag wiki.